# Why do we have a "quorum" badge on meta?

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm not talking about the quorum badge on the main outdoors site, but the one specifically on meta - since there's no meta of the meta site, as far as I can see it can't ever be earned! On SO for instance there's no quorum badge on meta.

Perhaps more of a general SE bug rather than the great outdoors, but am I missing something or is it not meant to be there?

Comment: There isn't one on the [Spanish.SE meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/badges).

Comment: Closed because it's already been cross-posted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120850/why-do-some-se-sites-have-a-quorum-badge-on-their-meta-page No need to duplicate the content.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I was just going to say I posted it over there when I realised it was probably a wider issue than just this site. Agreed with the close.

Comment: For anyone that's interested, this has now been solved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120850/why-do-some-se-sites-have-a-quorum-badge-on-their-meta-page/120881#120881